# Matching and returning values based on condition or ID

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, match, lookup

This seems like it should be fairly easy, but i'm having trouble with it.

Example: I have a dataframe with two columns `IDs` and `perc_change`. I want to know which unique `IDs` have had more than 30% change.

```
IDs <- c(1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,3,2,3,4,5,6,3)
perc_change <- c(50,40,60,70,80,30,20,40,23,25,10,30,12,7,70)
df <- data.frame(IDs, perc_change)
```

So far:

```
if (df$perc_change > 30) {
unique(df$IDs)
} else {
}
```

This obviously doesn't work because it returns all unique `IDs`. Should I be be finding the index and then matching it or soemthing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `[` to subset and take the `unique` - i.e. no need for `if/else` conditions

```
 with(df, unique(IDs[perc_change > 30]))
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

We could do so, to get the values of each ID:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(IDs) %>% 
    filter(perc_change > 30) %>% 
    mutate(values = paste0(perc_change, collapse = ","), .keep="unused") %>% 
    distinct(IDs, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
    IDs values     
  <dbl> <chr>      
1     1 50,40,70,80
2     2 60,40      
3     3 70
```

Answer (score 1):

We can group, filter and count using dplyr

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% 
    group_by(IDs) %>% 
    filter(perc_change > 30) %>% 
    count(IDs)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   IDs [3]
    IDs     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     4
2     2     2
3     3     1
```

Comment: Is there a way to possibly retrieve the exact ```perc_change``` values in the output tibble?

Answer (score 0):

```
unique(df[df$perc_change > 30,"IDs"])
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.